# Is transaction malleability an issue with Monero?

Tags: transaction-confirmation, attack, double-spending-attack

Is transaction malleability an issue with Monero, like it is in Bitcoin?

If so, is there an identified possibility to solve it?

If it isn't an issue, what makes the difference?

Comment: One different between monero and bitcoin is that in monero, you pay from an address instead of a txid. This means that transaction malleability wouldn't effect payment channels.

Comment: Can elaborate your point? What does it mean concretely?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At section `4.3.3` of `One-Time Ring Signatures` in the [MRL-003](https://lab.getmonero.org/pubs/MRL-0003.pdf) it is specified how the Monero network protect itself from transaction malleability (invalidating attempts of forcing invalid data in the key set).

I don't think Monero is completely immune since someone could create a bad client exploiting the protocol and with enough users using it the network could become vulnerable, this is a plausible scenario but very unlikely, hence why its important users download binaries and/or compile the source code only from the official getmonero.org website or the [github](https://github.com/monero-project).